# Json parse with in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, parsing

I want use autocompleted for searhing my site.

I use this function in PHP :

```
    public function searchAutoCompleteAjax(){
    $keyword = Input::get('keyword');

    $result = array();
    if(!empty(trim($keyword))){
        $mongoResult = MongoDB::instance(true)->collection("items")->like('name',$keyword)->limit(0,5)->fetch();

        if($mongoResult){
            foreach ($mongoResult as $key => $item) {
                $result[] = $item['name'];
            }
        }
    }


    echo json_encode(array("error"=>0,"message"=>"Success","result"=>$result));
}
```

I get 5 query on this code, in this line

```
$mongoResult = MongoDB::instance(true)->collection("items")->like('name',$keyword)->limit(0,5)->fetch();
```

Now i want use this 5 queries in JavaScript.

This is my JavaScript Code:

```js
$(function(){
  var currencies = [
  
    { value: 'Value-1' },
    { value: 'Value-2' },
    { value: 'Value-3' },
    { value: 'Value-4' },
    { value: 'Value-5' },

  ];
  
  // setup autocomplete function pulling from currencies[] array
  $('#search-box').autocomplete({
    lookup: currencies,
    });
});
```

I want check JSON data in JavaScript. But not working i have any method.

How to check Json data in my Java Script?

Comment: I don't see a `lookup:` option to jQuery UI Autocomplete. Are you using a different autocomplete widget?

Comment: The option in jQuery UI Autocomplete is `source:`. The documentation explains clearly how to use it with JSON. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: Do you want to know how to parse json into an object or how to search for something in the parsed json?

Comment: @Barmar

$('#search-box').autocomplete({
    lookup: currencies,
    });

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers support usage of JSON.parse() which can be used as follows.

```
var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

However, for those which don't you can use the jQuery method.
For best results use the following.

```
var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}';
var obj = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
```

Well, after parsing as JSON, you can use obj as an array and get data from it. For example, to get the first entry, in the json, use obj[0].fieldName.

For example,

```
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.employees[1].firstName + " " + obj.employees[1].lastName;
```

See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp) for further reference.

Comment: Thanks for sharing but how to apply in my javascript code?